# Vb.net: how to get hard disk/ssd name

Tags: vb.net

I need to find a code that gives me the name of the hard drive disk/ssd from the computer where i am executing the code (ex. crucial bx200 ssd or western digital hdd ).
I google it a lot and the only thing that i found similar was the model name, i don't know if it even is possible but there must be a code like this somewhere.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you will need to query the WMI information to get this.

Here is an example to get the local disk, and was taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms257346(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

```
Imports System
Imports System.Management

Public Class Query_SelectQuery

    Public Overloads Shared Function _
        Main(ByVal args() As String) As Integer

        Dim selectQuery As SelectQuery
        selectQuery = New SelectQuery("Win32_LogicalDisk")
        Dim searcher As ManagementObjectSearcher
        searcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery)

        Dim disk As ManagementObject
        For Each disk In searcher.Get()
            Console.WriteLine(disk.ToString())
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
        Return 0

    End Function

End Class
```

and here is some C# code to get a lot more information about each disk.

```
        var wqlQuery = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wqlQuery);

        foreach (var o in searcher.Get())
        {
            var disk = (ManagementObject)o;
            foreach (var property in disk.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", property.Name, property.Value);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I heard of WMI but i never understood it... don't i have to put a query in the selectQuery parameters? like in the website you got the code, there it was:
 Dim query As SelectQuery
        query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Environment", _
            "UserName = ""<system>""")
Thanks for your reply !